# jQuery/Javascript - printout the number of occurrences of a particular row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've a table generated from an external DB.
Using the below line I generate the rows of the table:

```
var row = $("<div id='row' class='divTableRow'><div class='divTableCell'>"+(i+1)+"</div><div class='divTableCell'>"+fullName+"</div><div class='divTableCell'>"+username+"</div><div class='divTableCell'>"+resName+"</div><div class='divTableCell'>"+finalRating+"</div><div class='divTableCell'>"+date+"</div></div>");

$(".divTable").append(row);
```

In the table a have a column called `username` which is basically a unique value to its user.

What I willing to do is to create a column, called for example `count` which should should the number of occurrences of the value `username`

Example:

```
      +----+------------+---------------+--------+-------+
      | No |  Full Name |   username    | Outlet | Count |
      +----+------------+---------------+--------+-------+
      | 1 | Stacy Gar   |  0649039233   |  Out2  |   2   |
      +----+------------+---------------+--------+-------+
      | 2 | Jeremy Fa   |  0349959522   |  Out5  |   1   |
      +----+------------+---------------+--------+-------+
      | 3 | Stacy Gar   |  0649039233   |  Out1  |   2   |
      +----+------------+---------------+--------+-------+
```

As you can see above in the table the `username` `0649039233` has bought from `Out1` and `Out2` that's why it has in the count column `2`

Any ideas on how I can achieve similar results in using jQuery or Javascript?

Comment: Important, I am stuck in something similar, I would love to see an answer

Comment: If you can create an example in jsfiddle I would be happy to help you.

Comment: didn't understand what exactly you want to achieve, if you can have the count number, why you need it in jquery?

Comment: @YanMayatskiy that's the thing, so far, I can't have the count number! I want to have it using jQuery, for that I doubt if jQuery.filter() is efficient

Comment: Are you generating the table via JavaScript or is it generated by a server side template?

Comment: @MehmetBaker it's generated by server side, but still as long as I have it in the front end, I can play with it and count the number of occurrences of `username`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each row, grab the user ID, then use [**filter()**](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) on the entire table to count the number of its occurrences:

```js
$('tr').each(function() {
  var userID = $(this).find('td:nth-child(3)').text(),
      count;

  count = $('td:nth-child(3)').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === userID;
  }).length;

  $(this).find('td:last').text(count);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><th>No<th>Full Name <th>username    <th>Outlet <th>Count
  <tr><td>1 <td>Stacy Gar <td>0649039233  <td>Out    <td>
  <tr><td>2 <td>Jeremy Fa <td>0349959522  <td>Out    <td>
  <tr><td>3 <td>Stacy Gar <td>0649039233  <td>Out    <td>
</table>
```

Comment: You nailed it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating the row you can save the userName and its occurrence number in this format:

> userName1:2;userName2:1;userName3:1;

':' separate the userName and it's occurrence and ';'separate records.

Before all things you must have two array.

```
var occurrence =[];
var userNames = [];
```

and when creating each row:

```
var index = userNames.indexOf(userName);
if(index > 0) // the user name is repeated. we only increase occurrence 
{
occurrence[index] = occurrence[index] + 1;
}
else
{
userNames.push(userName);
occurrence.push[1];
}
```

Now you have what you want:

occurrence of UserNames[i] = occurrence[i];

And you can use like this:

```
for(i=0;i<$('#yourTable').children('tr').length;i++) //or length-1 if you have header row
{
row = $('#yourTable').children('tr').eq(i); // or eq(i+1) if you have header row
row.children('td').eq(2).html(userNames[i]));
row.children('td').eq(4).html(occurrence[i]));
}
```